# Set text in MFC combo box without adding it to the list

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, mfc

I have an MFC combo box, specifically a type derived from `CComboBox`, created as a dropdown list box *without* the possibility to edit the selected entry, i.e. a simple list of selectable items.

I *do* support the possibility of *none* of the items being selected. I know I can just call `SetCurSel(-1)` and the edit field of the combo box will be empty until the user selects a "proper" item from the dropdown list. But I would actually prefer to show some kind of default text instead of just an empty field. So what I need to do is **set the edit field's text *without* adding that text to the item list or making the item user-editable**.

I tried `SetWindowText` on the combo box, without success. Based on a comment suggestion  I also tried to use `GetComboBoxInfo` to get a handle to the edit box (in the `COMBOBOXINFO::hwndItem`) member and calling `SetWindowText` on that, but this didn't work either (`GetComboBoxInfo` was successful, though). But I can't imagine this to be a particularly odd use case, so maybe it is possible by other means? If it helps, the combo box is actually ownerdrawn (`CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`).

Comment: are you try call [`GetComboBoxInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939(v=vs.85).aspx) and then use [`COMBOBOXINFO.hwndItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775798(v=vs.85).aspx) in call `SetWindowText` ?

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for the suggestion. But I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Maybe because it's ownerdraw?

Comment: IIRC (and maybe I don't) the edit box is passed to `WM_DRAWITEM` as itemID - 1.  Something like that anyway, put a breakpoint on it and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you already draw the combobox, than you know that

1. There is nothing selected if `lpdis->itemID == -1`
2. You receive the message when the edit control part has to be drawn. In this case `lpdis->itemState` has `ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT` set.

So you are allowed to draw whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

The combo box control has builtin support for cue banners. MFC's `CComboBox` exposes it through the [CComboBox::SetCueBanner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#setcuebanner) member:

> Cue text is a prompt that is displayed in the input area of the combo box control. The cue text is displayed until the user provides input.